# Построить интерференционную картину

Tags: python, математика, numpy, matplotlib

Есть код - интерференция света. Здесь в качестве длины волны значения 5. Но хотелось бы взять видимый спектр значения. Как можно реализовать?

```
from math import sqrt,sin,pi
from numpy import empty
from pylab import imshow,gray,show

wavelength = 5
k = 2*pi/wavelength
xi0 = 1.0
separation = 20.0      # Separation of centers in cm
side = 100.0           # Side of the square in cm
points = 500           # Number of grid points along each side
spacing = side/points  # Spacing of points in cm


# Calculate the positions of the centers of the circles
x1 = side/2 + separation/2
y1 = side/2
x2 = side/2 - separation/2
y2 = side/2

# Make an array to store the heights
xi = empty([points,points],float)

# Calculate the values in the array
for i in range(points):
    y = spacing*i
    for j in range(points):
        x = spacing*j
        r1 = sqrt((x-x1)**2+(y-y1)**2)
        r2 = sqrt((x-x2)**2+(y-y2)**2)
        xi[i,j] = xi0*sin(k*r1) + xi0*sin(k*r2)

# Make the plot
imshow(xi,origin="lower",extent=[0,side,0,side])
gray()
show()
```

Comment: ну видимо заменить wavelength = 5 на нужное вам значение, не?

Comment: да, верно! но когда меняю значения, то результат не такой ожидаемый...(

Comment: должно отображаться интерференционная картинка от двух источников волн

Comment: тогда вам нужно а) точнее описать задачу, б) подробнее описать, что вы пытались сделать, пытаясь ее решить, в) указать, что именно неправильно и что должно быть на самом деле. Описание ошибок типа "результат не такой ожидаемый" - бесполезны.

Comment: выше написала что ожидается

Comment: Построить интерференционную картину от двух сферических волн одинаковой амплитуды и частоты, каждая из которых задается законом синуса.

Comment: А в каких единицах тут длина волны? "максимум чувствительности приходится на 555 нм" - может тут 500 нм и есть `wavelength = 5` на самом деле? )

Comment: длина волны 5 см задан

Comment: `но когда меняю значения, то результат не такой ожидаемый` - на какое меняете значение, какой результат ожидаемый, какой получается?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Единицы измерения в коде имеют условный характер (какими назовете единицами, такие единицы и будут - хоть сантиметрами назовите, хоть метрами, программе все равно, главное чтобы везде одна и та же единица измерения была). Можно выбрать, что на самом деле единица измерения - метр, поставить длину волны 550 нанометров (550 * 10**-9), все другие размеры заменить более-менее пропорционально (в том числе сторону рисунка), тогда будет нормальная интерференционная картина:

```
wavelength = 550E-9 # 550 нм (550 * 10**-9 м)
k = 2*pi/wavelength
xi0 = 1.0
separation = wavelength*4  # между источниками 4 длины волны (0.0022 мм)
side = 1E-5  # Сторона рисунка - 0.01 мм
points = 500
spacing = side/points
```

Нужно понимать, что это не отображение интерференционной картины на стену (при проекции на стену из-за удаления от источников картина становится "больше"), а как бы "сечение" пространства плоскостью, проходящей через два источника, поэтому все величины (в том числе и сторона рисунка) такие маленькие.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Поняла! Спасибо большое!

Comment: такой вопрос что означают серые радиусы? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: серый цвет - промежуточное значение амплитуды?

Comment: Там где серая "перемычка" и серые радиусы - это по факту те места где волны интерферируют в 0

Comment: точки, где волны интерферируют​ в ноль - это максимумы. При чем здесь серые полосы? Заранее благодарю ответ!

Comment: Нет, максимумы/минимумы - это черные и белые полосы, там где волны наоборот усиливаются. В серых полосах промежуточное значение, т.е. 0. Если вместо статического графика сделать анимацию, то видно будет, что черные и белые полосы движутся, а в "серых зонах" - штиль, ничего не происходит, в этих областях волны от двух источников компенсируют друг друга.

Comment: Еще уточню: интерферируют волны тут везде, но где-то они складываются в одной фазе (максимум+максимум - получается максимум, минимум+минимум - получается минимум), а где-то в противофазе (максимум + минимум) - получается 0, "серая зона".

Comment: и еще последний вопрос...) немного не уверена в программе, вызывает вопросов насчет картинки интерференции. Как считаете с точки зрения физики все верно рассчитывает и показывает в результате исходный код верно? Заранее благодарю ответ.

Comment: Ну как сказать, если брать "мгновенный снимок", то примерно так и должно быть. В тазике с водой и двумя мушками так примерно и будет выглядеть интерференция) Но для света не будет видно таких волн, будут освещенные зоны там, где на картинке черно-белые полоски, и затемненные зоны - там где "серые зоны" на картинке. С математической точки зрения в любом случае все верно)

Comment: интересный ответ! спасибо вам большое))) вы супер)